# menu items height

Tags: asp.net

In Site.master, 
How I do set the height of navigation menu items. I want all the menu items to have equal height and centered text.

```
 <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" StaticMenuItemStyle-Height="148px" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal" 
                 StaticSelectedStyle-CssClass="selected" >
                <Items>
                    <asp:MenuItem   NavigateUrl="~/_UILayer1/AdminAcctInfo.aspx"  Text="Admin Profile <br/>Info"/>
                    <asp:MenuItem  NavigateUrl="~/_UILayer1/BUsersAcctInfo.aspx" Text="Business Users <br/>Profile Info"/>
                    <asp:MenuItem  NavigateUrl="~/_UILayer1/FMMPublication.aspx" Text="Publication"/>

                </Items>
            </asp:Menu>
```

Neither the StaticMenuItemStyle-height  nor the height options seem to work

Thanks
Sun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't include the code for your CSS classes but this should get you going:

```
<asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server"  StaticMenuItemStyle-CssClass="MenuItem"
    Orientation="Horizontal"  >
    <Items>
        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/_UILayer1/AdminAcctInfo.aspx" Text="Admin Profile <br/>Info" />
        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/_UILayer1/BUsersAcctInfo.aspx" Text="Business Users <br/>Profile Info" />
        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/_UILayer1/FMMPublication.aspx" Text="Publication"  />
    </Items>
</asp:Menu>
```

CSS Class:

```
.MenuItem
{
    height: 150px; 
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help? [ASP.NET MenuItem Individual Styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/705440/asp-net-menuitem-individual-styles)

Or depending on your .Net version (you need 4.0 for this)  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366731.aspx