# setting the background color of the items in a menu

Tags: asp.net

I have a menu. This is my codes.

```
    <Items>
        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="#" Text="New Item" Value="New Item">

            <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="#" Text="New Item" Value="New Item"></asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="#" Text="New Item New Item" Value="New Item"></asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="#" Text="New Item" Value="New Item"></asp:MenuItem>
        </asp:MenuItem>
```

My question is how do I set the background color of my subitems in the menu? I also need to know how to set the width of the column where all the subitems is display?

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio, if you select the ASP `Menu` tag in the source view, the properties window will list the available properties for this particular ASP tag.

Then select `DynamicMenuItemStyle` from the available options and set the ASP `BackColor` property to whatever.

Also you can select `DynamicHoverStyle` from the available options and set the ASP `BackColor` property to whatever for a mouseover effect.

---

Here is the code that this would generate (nested within the `Menu` tag, placed above the `Items` tag):

```
<DynamicHoverStyle BackColor = "red" />
<DynamicMenuItemStyle BackColor = "blue" />
```

---

***Note***: use `StaticMenuItemStyle` *to affect the top-most menu items, and* `DynamicMenuItemStyle` *to affect all submenu items.*

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<Items>
    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="#" Text="New Item" Value="New Item">
    <asp:MenuItem style="background-color:red;" NavigateUrl="#" Text="New Item" Value="New Item"></asp:MenuItem>
    <asp:MenuItem style="background-color:red;" NavigateUrl="#" Text="New Item New Item" Value="New Item"></asp:MenuItem>
    <asp:MenuItem style="background-color:red;" NavigateUrl="#" Text="New Item" Value="New Item"></asp:MenuItem>
    </asp:MenuItem>
</Items>
```

Comment: You just have to modify the style attribute: style="background-color:red;width:30px".

Comment: Just a question, when I code them in asp, it said that style is not a valid attribute of asp:MenuItem. What does it means and can I still proceed?

Comment: This post may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/705440/asp-net-menuitem-individual-styles.