# ASP.NET: How to set the cssclass for a menuitem on codebehind

Tags: asp.net, css, menu, styles, menuitem

How can I set a different cssclass for each menuitem of a ASP.NET Menu control from codebehind?
All of these menuitems are at level2. So something like this would not work because all of the menuitems on level2 would end up with the same cssclass(level2class) and I want to be able to set diferent styles for each of them:

```
<LevelMenuItemStyles>
    <asp:MenuItemStyle CssClass="level1class"/>
    <asp:MenuItemStyle CssClass="level2class"/>    
</LevelMenuItemStyles>
```

So I'd like to do something like this:

```
MenuItem myMenu = new MenuItem();
myMenu.Text = "MyMenu";
Menu1.Items.Add(myMenu); //Menu1 is the name of the asp.net Menu control

foreach (DataRow row in myDataTable.Rows)
 {
    MenuItem myItem = new MenuItem();
    string myItemName = row["myItemName"].ToString();
    myItem.Text = myItemName; 

    //HERE COMES THE PROBLEM. I'M NOT ABLE TO DEFINE A DIFFERENT CSSCLASS FOR EACH MENUITEM.
    if (myItemName == "x1")
    { 
          myItem.CssClass = "x1class";  //THIS DOES NOT WORK AS MENUITEM DOES NOT HAVE CSSCLASS PROPERTY
    }
   else if (myItemName == "x2")
   {
         myItem.CssClass = "x2class";  //THIS DOES NOT WORK AS MENUITEM DOES NOT HAVE CSSCLASS PROPERTY
   }

   myMenu.ChildItems.Add(myItem);
}
```

ANOTHER TRIED ALTERNATIVE THAT COULD WORK BUT AM STUCK ALSO:

```
if (myItemName == "x1")
 { 
     MenuItemStyle ms = new MenuItemStyle();
     ms.CssClass = "x1class";
     //HOW DO I SET ms OBJECT TO THE myItem OBJECT?
}
else if (myItemName == "x2")
{
     MenuItemStyle ms = new MenuItemStyle();
     ms.CssClass = "x2class";
     //HOW DO I SET ms OBJECT TO THE myItem OBJECT?
}
```

Thank you

Comment: By the way, a third alternative that I'm working with is trying to set the cssclass of the menuitem on the menuitemdatabound event. But for some reason, the way I'm adding items to the menu doesn't triggers the menuitemdatabound event and so I never get there.

Comment: It looks like this might work:  [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/705440/asp-net-menuitem-individual-styles][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/705440/asp-net-menuitem-individual-styles

Answer (score 0):

But if you really want to a CSS class you might be able to use the Attributes.Add method... something like this `myItem.Attributes.Add( "class", "pretty" );`

Comment: Have you tried that? Menuitem object doesn't have Attributes property available.

Comment: No, that's why I said might work :-)  other thing to try would be to assign the menu item and ID and possibly set the clientidmode to static and reference it via css that way... or better yet I would reference this list items by their css nth-child() selector http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

Comment: the thing is that the number/text of the menuitems will vary a lot and so not sure how this would work with your idea.

Comment: Yeah, you might want to take a look at this link or you may already have:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366731.aspx

Comment: Hi Nathan. Yes, I have. The link shows how to create style for a whole level (first code I posted above), but I need to create style for specific menu items. That is what I`m not finding how to. thanks,

Comment: I found out how. Posting here in case someone needs. Just add the html tag with the cssclass in the codebehind: myItem.Text = "<div class='x1class'>worked</div>";

Comment: @user2974961 You can also add your comment as an answer (and mark it as the accepted answer) as others might not see your comment.