# Conditionally format a menu item's background color?

Tags: c#, asp.net, menuitem

I have this code in C# code-behind:

```
for (int i = PIndex2; i < PIndex2 + 10 && i < PCount; i++)
{
    NavMenu.Items.Add(new MenuItem
    {
        Text = (i + 1).ToString(),
        NavigateUrl = Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath + "?page=" + (i + 1).ToString()
    });
    if (i == PIndex)
    {
        MenuItemStyle ms = new MenuItemStyle();
        ms.CssClass = "div.navmenu ul li a:focus";
    }
}
```

I want to change the background color if the page is the current page (which I keep in a variable called PIndex).  I can't seem to find the proper syntax to do it.  I have tried using both a:focus and a:active in my CssClass statement, neither of which worked.

My CSS is as follows:

```
/* NAV MENU */
div.navmenu
{
    padding: 2px 0px 2px 4px;
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

div.navmenu ul
{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: auto;
    color: White;
}

div.navmenu ul li a, div.navmenu ul li a:visited
{
    background-color: #465c71;    
/*    background-color: white;    */
    border: 1px #4e667d solid;  
    color: white;
    display: block;
    line-height: 1.35em;
    padding: 4px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

div.navmenu ul li a:hover
{
    background-color: white;
    color: #465c71;
    text-decoration: none;
}

div.navmenu ul li a:active, div.navmenu ul li a:focus,
{
    background-color: #cfdbe6 !important;
    /*    color: #cfdbe6;  */
    color: White; 
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Hover works fine.  However, once I'm on the page I want the item's background color to be what's in a:active.

Comment: Is this a Windows Forms app? Or a WPF app?

Comment: @JeffFerguson - It's ASP.NET Web App.

Comment: Define CSS class, add class attribute to menu item. See duplicate.

Comment: If you read the duplicate, you'd know you can't add a class attribute.  And that question isn't a duplicate of this one.

Comment: See the ["found out how"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19883721/asp-net-how-to-set-the-cssclass-for-a-menuitem-on-codebehind#comment29638465_19884003) comment. Please expand your question on what part specifically you're having trouble. Do you know you can style HTML elements with CSS?

Comment: I'm using CSS, and it's not working.

Comment: What did that code do with `ms` afterwards? Please show all relevant code. You need to apply the style to the menu item.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  The code with ms did nothing.  Didn't change the background, and it didn't break anything.  The page loaded, but without the colors I expected for that associated page number.

Comment: Use "@username" if you want the user to be notified of your comment. Anyhow you need to do something with the ms variable. Show your code, with the MenuItemStyle.

Comment: @CodeCaster - Question has been edited to show my exact code that isn't working.

Comment: @JohnnyBones, try see about [Menu.StaticSelectedStyle Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.menu.staticselectedstyle(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Grundy - If you put that as an answer, I'll give ya 25 points. :)  Your suggestion led to this question, which (with a bit of tweaking) solved my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7148872/asp-net-problems-with-static-selected-style-for-a-selected-page-on-the-menu

Comment: @JohnnyBones, methinks, better mark this question as duplicate, or you can put your own answer with your tweaking for those who find this question in future :-)